# How to add javascript functions to events using ASP:ComboBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Please have mercy, working in ASP is not my native environment. I have a [ComboBox](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Custom_ASPNET_ComboxBox_Control.aspx#1316) that is populated with ListItems during the load of the page. I need to get information out of the selected items value when the user selects one of the entries, but every hook for an event I have tried has done nothing.

What can I do to cause a selected index change to fire my Javascript?

The control: `<asp:ComboBox ID="cboFighterGym" name="cboFighterGym" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False"
                                            DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CaseSensitive="False"
                                            ItemInsertLocation="Append" onchange="hello();" ClientIDMode="Static" >
                                        </asp:ComboBox>`

```
var sel = document.getElementById("cboFighterGym");
        alert(sel.toString()); // This outputs [object HTMLDivElement]
        sel.onchange = function () {
            alert("Selected value: " + this.value); // This never happens
        };
```

When I run it the section appears to look like this:

```
<div id="cboFighterGym" name="cboFighterGym" onchange="hello();" onFocus="alert(&#39;Hello&#39;)" style="display:inline-block;">
<table id="Table" class="ajax__combobox_inputcontainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0px;border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:5px;">
    <tr>
        <td class="ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer"><input name="cboFighterGym$TextBox" type="text" id="TextBox" autocomplete="off" /></td><td class="ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer"><button id="Button" type="button" style="visibility:hidden;"></button></td>
    </tr>
</table><ul id="OptionList" class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">
    <li>Select a Gym</li><li>Other</li><li>555 555, Oregon</li>

</ul><input type="hidden" name="cboFighterGym$HiddenField" id="HiddenField" value="0" />
```

Comment: Are you using the ComboBox from link or the one from ASP .Net Ajax Control Toolkit? http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx

Comment: Yes Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using asp.net 4, you can utilize the new [ClientIDMode](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=492), to give your dropdown a predictable name, then select it and subscribe to the onchange event in JavaScript

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="selectId" ClientIDMode="Static" />

var sel = document.getElementById("selectId");
sel.onchange = function(){
    alert("Selected value: " + this.value);
};
```

Or you can give it a unique classname, and essentially do the same thing:

```
var sel = document.getElementsByClassName("uniqueClass")[0];
sel.onchange = function(){
    alert("Selected value: " + this.value);
};
```

Comment: the javascript throws "sel is nul" in spite of the ID matching

Comment: @Pyrodante - I assume you put the script in the `head`?  The dom probably isn't ready.  Move the script block with this code to the very end of your document's **body**

Comment: Well the error went away, but now it doesn't do anything again. I put a  alert(sel.toString()); and was output: [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: @Pyrodante - post the Javascript to your question as an update

Comment: I fear this is painfully rudimentary, but as an Android developer being asked to work on another persons project, I am a bit out of my element.

Comment: @Pyrodante - it looks like you're grabbing the dropdown just fine.  And setting it like the above should work - did you try selecting one of the options from your dropdown to make sure the alert hit?

Comment: changing the selection from the default to another option does not create an alert, neither does typing, tabbing in or out, or refreshing the page after a selection has been made. I even put in the VB side cboFighterGym.Attributes.Add("onFocus", "alert('Hello')"). to no avail, but the text box below functions as expected when the same code is tied to it.

Comment: @Pyrodante - have you checked the chrome console for errors?  You might also double check that you don't have duplicate elements with duplicate ids.

Comment: @Pyrodante - the next step would be to look at the code asp.net generates and make sure it's correct, then take (a subset of) the generated code and put it into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and post that as a new question here on stack overflow

Comment: @Pyrodante - then I would start to pull out the html asp.net is generating and try to spot the problem, or re-create it in a fiddle (link in previous comment).  Posting a fiddle to a SO question will help people debug your code

Comment: I have posted the HTML result, I am going to start some tests myself.

Comment: @Pyrodante - looking at your html, it looks like you don't have any dropdown lists at all - it looks like there's some sort of ajax drop down being generated.  The native dom events **will not** work here.  You're going to have to find the documentation for whatever this ajax drop down is, and use it to find out how to subscribe to the change event

Comment: It is a combobox, and a link to what I have found for its documentation was in the original question. I think this was used because they wanted an auto complete drop down

Comment: Did you look at the code in the link under listing: **Listing 2. JavaScript to display selected item text on the TextBox**

Comment: yes, IIRC in the example they use a button to fire that method, I am trying to find a hook I can use to fire it when the user selects and option.