# How to make a combo box that allow me to display data based on selection?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

So here is the deal, I have a registration page, in that they need to put their home gym, I load the already registered gyms from the DB on load via ASP and put them into a AJAX Combobox. I do this because I want it to be an auto-complete box. When a user selects a gym, that gyms information needs to populate beneath, if they select "other" they should be able to fill out the information themselves.

I can load the info from the database via ASP, but haven't figured out a way to stash it so that when a user selects an option and clicks the button, that entries data loads.

Related: [How to add javascript functions to events using ASP:ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9319563/706836)

PS: I know this isn't the best formed question, but time does not permit me to learn an entirely new system to fix what to my boss seems like a simple problem.

Comment: Actually it is pretty easy. Unfortunately, I don't know ASP.Net. But if you know how to set a Page/Web service return plain text or JSON format then it is a start.

Comment: Thanks for at least giving me a direction! Basically I was given a broken half completed project and told 'fix it'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to put everything in an asp.net updatepanel.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx

You can put the combobox and the rest of the "fill in" controls inside of the update panel.

Set teh combobox to "Auto-Postback" and handle the "SelectedIndexChanged" event.  On this event, populate the "fill-in" data.

Note: this may not be the "best" way, but if you're trying to get this up and running, this will be very fast.

Here's an example of a simple situation (should suffice for your situation).  Just make sure the updatepanel is inside of the form.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                 <ContentTemplate>
                 //Just put all your stuff in here.

                 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: with the auto-postback wont that require the page to refresh when the user selects an option?

Comment: No because it's in an updatepanel which handles the ajax callback to the server for you.  That's the whole purpose of an updatepanel - to abstract an ajax call and make it easy.  No javascript, no json needed.  Just don't overuse it.

Comment: Check out the link, you'll see how easy it is to use.

Comment: Added an example for you, you don't need everything in the article for your situation.

Comment: unfortunately, I was pulled off for the moment to finish a piece of my Android project, I think this is correct, and will accept as soon as I verify that

Comment: Sorry for the delay @swannee, this is perfect!